# How to remove empty lines from a nested list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I call data from Google Sheets, I get an answer in the form of a dictionary with a nested dictionary, since I have two strings combined, **the response from the server returns empty strings**, how can I get the edited response and write it to a new list?

```
{'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS',
 'range': "'Sheet1'!A3:A964",
 'values': [['Sticker | Fnatic | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | Fnatic (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | FaZe | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | FaZe (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | TYLOO | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | TYLOO (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | G2 | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | G2 (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | Ninjas in Pyjamas | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | Ninjas in Pyjamas (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | Astralis | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | Astralis (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | Natus Vincere | 2020 RMR',
             '',
             'Sticker | Natus Vincere (Holo) | Katowice 2015']]}
```

I need:

```
new_list =
['Sticker | Fnatic | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | Fnatic (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | FaZe | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | FaZe (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | TYLOO | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | TYLOO (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | G2 | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | G2 (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | Ninjas in Pyjamas | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | Ninjas in Pyjamas (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | Astralis | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | Astralis (Holo) | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | Natus Vincere | 2020 RMR',
 'Sticker | Natus Vincere (Holo) | Katowice 2015']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple list comprehension with checker will do the job (assuming data is the name of variable that the response is being stored):

```
new_ls = [each for each in data['values'][0] if each != '']
```

`new_ls` would look like:

```
['Sticker | Fnatic | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | Fnatic (Holo) | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | FaZe | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | FaZe (Holo) | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | TYLOO | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | TYLOO (Holo) | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | G2 | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | G2 (Holo) | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | Ninjas in Pyjamas | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | Ninjas in Pyjamas (Holo) | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | Astralis | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | Astralis (Holo) | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | Natus Vincere | 2020 RMR', 'Sticker | Natus Vincere (Holo) | Katowice 2015']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter it out using `filter()`

```py
new_list = list(filter(None, c['values'][0]))
```